# JQueryUI autocomplete search with Django not working

Tags: ajax, django, jquery-ui, autocomplete, django-templates

I am working on a project with Django, for a restaurant management system. I wanted to use an autocomplete feature to take orders at the table.
As far as I understand JQueryUI function `autocomplete()` is what I need.
However I cannot seem to get it to work.

Following is my my HTML code for the page. It works in such a way that once the number of people in the party is inserted the same number of form input fiels is inserted in the table by a Javascrip script.

**addOrder.html**

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" %}></script>
    <script src={% static "js/jquery-ui.min.js" %}></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/createOrderIn.js" %}> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/autocompleteDrink.js" %}></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src={% static "js/autocompleteMenu.js" %}></script>
    <style>
        .move {
            margin: 30px;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Add Order</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="move">
    <form action="/orders/addOrder" method="post" id="the-form" class="ui-widget">
        <label> Party of </label>
        <input type="text" id="people">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit order">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the script I use to spawn new form input fields

**createOrderIn.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var previous = 0;
    var considered = 0;

    $("#people").keyup(function ( ) {
        var actual = this.value;
        if(actual==null){
            actual=1;
         }
         var toAdd = actual-previous;
         previous = actual;
         if(toAdd > 0){
            for(var i=0; i<toAdd; i++){
                considered+=1;
                var htmlToAdd = $("<div class="+considered+"><input type=\"text\" name=\"menu_"+considered+"\" id=\"menu\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"drink_"+considered+"\" value=\"No drink\" id=\"drink\"><br></div>");
                $("#the-form").append(htmlToAdd);
            }
        }
        else{
            for(var j=0; j<(-1*toAdd); j++) {
                if (considered > 0) {
                    $("."+considered).remove();
                    considered -= 1;
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The following are the relative Python/Django files

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.ordersIndex, name = "index"),
    path('changeStatus/<int:pk>', views.changeStatus, name="changeStatus"),
    path('addOrder', views.addOrder, name="addOrder"),
    path('addOrderRender', views.addOrderRender, name="addOrderRender"),
    path('getDrinks', views.getDrinks, name="getDrinks"),
    path('getMenus', views.getMenus, name="getMenu"),
]
```

**views.py (only function `getMenus()`)**

```
def getMenus(request):
    print("I am called")
    if request.is_ajax():
        q = request.GET.get('term', '')
        menus = Menu.objects.filter(name__contains=q)
        results=[]
        for menu in menus:
            menu_json = {}
            menu_json['name'] = menu.name
            menu_json['n_courses'] = menu.number_of_courses
            menu_json['price'] = menu.price
            results.append(menu_json)
        data = json.dump(results)
    else:
        data = 'fail'
    mimetype = 'application/json'
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

And lastly this is the function that is supposed to use JQueryUI to make the ajax call and retrieve the possible menu's

**autocompleteMenu.js**

```
$(function() {
  $("#menu").autocomplete({
    source: "/orders/getMenus/",
  });
});
```

As you can probably see from the `getMenus()` function in `views.py` I also print a check line ("I am called"), which sure enough does not get printed on console. Also even by switching the `autocomplete()` `source` parameter to a local array there is no result.

I do feel like I am doing some very naive mistake but I really cannot seem to figure it out (I am also pretty new with JQuery).

I think the error should be in the provided files, but I'll be happy to post edits in just in case

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the problem was due to the fact that I had to bind autocomplete to the id of the newly created id's (which I changed to classes). Also the JSON data must have a `lable` field, (and I had to use `json.dumps()`, not `json.dump()` :p).
The followings did the trick:

**createOrderIn.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var previous = 0;
    var considered = 0;

    $("#people").keyup(function ( ) {
        var actual = this.value;
        if(actual==null){
            actual=1;
         }
         var toAdd = actual-previous;
         previous = actual;
         if(toAdd > 0){
            for(var i=0; i<toAdd; i++){
                considered+=1;
                var htmlToAdd = $("<div class="+considered+"><input type=\"text\" name=\"menu_"+considered+"\" class=\"menu\"><input type=\"text\" name=\"drink_"+considered+"\" value=\"No drink\" class=\"drink\"><br></div>");
                $("#the-form").append(htmlToAdd);
                $('#the-form').find('input[class=menu]:last').autocomplete({
                    source: "/orders/getMenus"
                });
                $('#the-form').find('input[class=drink]:last').autocomplete({
                    source: "/orders/getDrinks"
                });
            }
        }
        else{
            for(var j=0; j<(-1*toAdd); j++) {
                if (considered > 0) {
                    $("."+considered).remove();
                    considered -= 1;
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**views.py**

```
def getDrinks(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        q = request.GET.get('term', '')
        drinks = Drink.objects.filter(name__contains=q)
        results=[]
        for drink in drinks:
            drink_json = {}
            drink_json['label'] = drink.name
            results.append(drink_json)
        data = json.dumps(results)
    else:
        data = 'fail'
    mimetype = 'application/json'
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)


def getMenus(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        q = request.GET.get('term', '')
        menus = Menu.objects.filter(name__contains=q)
        results=[]
        for menu in menus:
            menu_json = {}
            menu_json['label'] = menu.name
            menu_json['id'] = menu.number_of_courses
            results.append(menu_json)
        data = json.dumps(results)
    else:
        data = 'fail'
    mimetype = 'application/json'
    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```